# Remove an item from a copy of an array without removing it from the original array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, copy, instance

How can I remove an object from a copy of an array without removing it from the original?

I have a global variable :

```
    var userTrickList = [];
```

And inside a function, I make a copy of that global array :

```
    var tempUserTrickList = userTrickList;
```

Then I use the `removeItem` function that I created to remove a certain object.

```
    removeItem(considerTrick.IDName, tempUserTrickList);


    function removeItem(item, list) {
        //takes a string as 'item', finds in the array as 'list', 
        //then removes it from the list.
        for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            if(item === list[i])
            {
                list.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is, this function removes it from the `userTrickList` too.

Any ideas? It's definitely a problem in `"removeItem(considerTrick.IDName, tempUserTrickList);"`,  but I can't think of a solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `.slice(0)` to clone an array.

```
var tempUserTrickList = userTrickList.slice(0);
```

Credits:
http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array

Comment: i did check this and this is not working You have to use slice instead of splice.bcoz splice will affect the source array. http://fiddle.jshell.net/QRK4Q/

Comment: Thank you Daniel number 2! And Manishankar! (number 1...)
Worked like a charm :') This community is sick!

Comment: @Manishankar You're absolutely correct. The example I linked to correctly used `slice` and I incorrectly added the `p` when I copied it. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @Manishankar I'm not sure what you mean by that. I updated my answer to use `slice()`, as is appropriate.

Comment: @Daniel here your OP post userTrickList.splice(0); . there is it splice.

Comment: yes i used slice lol. thats why I thanked both Dan 2 and you manishankar ^^ i have had no problems with it at all :D

Comment: While this is correct, I added an ES6 approach using the spread operator as an additional answer.

Answer (score 2):

use this function for your requirement

```
function removeElementFromArray(data,target) {
var temp=new Array();   
for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i]!=target){
        temp.push(data[i]);
    }
}
return temp; }
```

here data is original array and target is the element you want to remove from array
this function will return array without containing the removed item.

Answer (score 1):

Try, It copy the original array

```
var tempUserTrickList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userTrickList));
```

[Demo CopyArray](http://fiddle.jshell.net/QRK4Q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  if (arr[i] === item) {
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    i -= 1;
    l -= 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's method of cloning an array is absolutely correct, but since I don't see an ES6-oriented answer, I'll offer up an alternative solution:

We can just as easily use the spread operator to clone an array, so we don't have to use the slice call.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const copy = [...arr];
copy.pop();
console.log(arr);  // returns [1, 2, 3]
console.log(copy); // returns [1, 2]
```